# 'Ether' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I'm trying to do programming with Scapy on Ubuntu by doing this.

```
>>> for lsb in range (1,256) :
. . .        ip =  "10.0.1."  +str (lsb)
. . .        arpRequest = Ether (dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP (pdst=ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
. . .        arpResponse = srp1 (arpRequest, timeout=1, verbose=0)
. . .        if arpResponse :
. . .                   print "IP:  " + arpResponse.psrc + " MAC:  " + arpResponse.hwsrc
```

Once I type these commands I got this.

```
. . . 
Traceback  (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
NameError:  name 'Ether' is not defined
```

Can somebody help me if Ether is the command on Ubuntu or am I missing something?

Comment: Formatted code and error response

Comment: @niemmi: I don't know if you realize this, but SO decided that the messages in the Help and Improvements queue should show up in both the revision and in a comment.  That's partly why I rarely give a message in that queue.  I guess it's meant as a place to tell the OP what still needs to be done.

Comment: @zondo Wasn't aware of that, thanks for letting me know. I'll try to keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Where do you think Ether came from?  Where did you get this code?

Comment: The code was from a video tutorial of doing programming with Scapy. But I'm trying to see if Ether has another command word on ubuntu

Comment: Or would it be that scapy.all needs to be changed?

Comment: The platform has nothing to do with it.  You just haven't defined `Ether`.  Perhaps you forgot to put `from scapy.all import *` at the top?

Comment: So should I put the scapy.all down before doing the steps?

Comment: We do not know what video you're following, you did not post a link.  But, if you are following a video on scapy, most people would assume you have understanding on how python modules work.  If you don't you should look at that before attempting to understand scapy.

Comment: Thanks I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Scapy. Just add `from scapy.all import *` at the beginning of your code.